# How should prevent the changes affect in more than one model angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
    namespace.aaa=response;
    namespace.bbb=response;
```

response is the data coming from service. I just assigned them to two models(aaa,bbb). Then assigned model (**namespace.aaa**) to a grid. If I made changes in the grid, it obviously affected the model (**namespace.aaa**). It is fine. but its affecting another model (**namespace.bbb**) also.

How should prevent this? I need both models. Unable to repeat service for assigning data to model one by one.

Comment: can you show your html code as well

Comment: sorry, its in server machine. Cannot take code from that. What I mentioned above, is same that implemented in my coding also. What I need is, prevent changes affect in model(namespace.bbb) while changing data in model(namespace.aaa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to use `angular.copy();` for "bbb" model - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Comment: No problem ! Have a nice (development) day !

Answer (score 1):

You should create a copy of your response, by using `angular.copy();`

When assigning values to a object, in JavaScript there are two types of assignments: assign by value and assign by reference. Strings, numbers, booleans are assigned by value, other objects are assigned by reference, so in your code `namespace.aaa` and `namespace.bbb` are both pointing to original `response` object, and when you assign `namespace.aaa` to grid, it also points to original `response`. So use `angular.copy();` for one of your assignments.

More about angular.copy() - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

More about value assignments in JS - http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch11_02.htm

Comment: hi @domakas, thanks for clear information. now its working fine.